# Send to a recipient, while listing others in the sent-to list

Tags: c#, email, smtp, mailkit

I'd like to send an email to a single person, yet have the "sent to" list display a number of people. (I don't want those other people to receive the email).

A number of articles ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543333/different-mime-and-smtp-from-addresses) and [here](http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/set_from_and_other_headers.html#SendToUndisclosed)) suggest it's perfectly legal to specify different values for smtp address and mime addresses.

I'm using MailKit and this is what I have so far:

```
var message = new MimeMessage();
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("MeetingOfficeA", "noreply@office.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Fidel Perez-Smith", "fidel@office.com"));

message.Headers.Add("To", "john.doe@office.com"); //this line actually sends the email to John Doe, which I don't want

message.Subject = "Testing";
message.Body = new TextPart ("plain") { Text = @"Testing 123" };

MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient();
client.Connect("smtpserver.office.com");
client.Send(message);
```

Is there something I can add so only Fidel receives the email, yet it looks like it was sent to multiple people?

(The question in link 1 is similar, but mainly discusses the 'from' addresses. I think my question should not be marked as duplicate because it relates to the 'to addresses' and will make it easier for other users to find. After all, it took a while to find that other link when I was researching my particular issue).

Comment: What's wrong with the answer you linked to?

Comment: Hi Amit, they're specifying a custom from address. I'd list to specify a custom "to list"

Comment: The answer specifically mentions you can do whatever you want, including setting the "to list". Did you try?

Comment: Hi Amit, yes, setting the "To" value in the message.Headers collection ended up sending the email to the person. (It seems to be just an alias for the "message.To" property) I'm open to using other smtp clients if that helps

Comment: Where is the code that failed?

Comment: I've updated the code sample. It's the line that starts with "message.Headers.Add"

Comment: You're being sloppy. Read the linked answer again

Comment: Hi Amit, are you referring the the bit of code that says "client.Send (MimeMessage message..."? Does that actually work for you?

Comment: If you are not satisfied with that answer, explain why

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Different MIME and SMTP from addresses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543333/different-mime-and-smtp-from-addresses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet will make it *look like* the message was sent to both Fidel Perez-Smith and John Doe, but in reality, it will only be sent to Fidel Perez-Smith:

```
var message = new MimeMessage ();
message.From.Add (new MailboxAddress ("MeetingOfficeA", "noreply@office.com"));
message.To.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Fidel Perez-Smith", "fidel@office.com"));
message.To.Add (new MailboxAddress ("John Doe", "john.doe@office.com");
message.Subject = "Testing";
message.Body = new TextPart ("plain") { Text = @"Testing 123" };

using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
    client.Connect ("smtpserver.office.com");
    client.Send (message, new MailboxAddress ("MeetingOfficeA", "noreply@office.com"), new [] { new MailboxAddress ("Fidel Perez-Smith", "fidel@office.com") });
    client.Disconnect (true);
}
```